# Error "'mongodump' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." trying to dump the database from mongodb 5.0

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I am trying to dump a database from mongodb where i am getting not recognized error on running the command from command line as admin.
mongodump --db ninjago,
I have added the path variable in environment variables for mongodb. I am still getting the error.
Please help. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to additionally install [MongoDB Database Tools](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/) in order to use `mongodump` in the CLI. If you need to restore the data, after installing MongoDB Database Tools you will be able to use the `mongorestore` in the CLI as well.

You can download the MongoDB Database Tools on [official MongoDB download page](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools), and then you can follow the [official installation guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/installation/installation/).

Comment: Is there anything else i need to do other than installing MongoDB tools, I have installed the MongoDB database tools, but still the dump is not working.

Comment: Do you have the same error or? Is command available now?

Comment: I have the same error

Comment: Did you add DB Tools to the system's `PATH` environment variable?